# Как загрузить страницу в Iframe?

Tags: iframe, javascript

На странице сайта есть обычный пустой iframe.

Нужно программно, через js, загрузить туда другую страницу (auth.php) этого же сайта, через js заполнить форму авторизации в фрейме и выполнить запрос.

Как можно туда через js загрузить эту страницу?

Answer (score 1):

> Как можно туда через js загрузить эту страницу?

Поменять значение атрибута src у iframe на адрес нужной страницы.

Comment: Спасибо. А как можно обращаться через js к элементам, которые находятся внутри ifrime?

Comment: Доступ к окну происходит через свойство contentWindow.

Поэтому, для примера, как-то так:         

        iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("login");